# QuestDB SELECT returning special chars, but Postgres does not

Tags: php, postgresql, questdb

I successfully set up a simple `PostgreSQL` database and can `SELECT` and `print` rows as expected, using this code:

```
// PG
$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'pg_test_db';
$username = 'postgres';
$password = 'admin';

$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
echo '<pre>';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_table");
try {
    $stmt->execute(array());
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

My problem occurs when I try to do the same for my `QuestDB` test table, using this code:

```
// QDB
$dbName = 'qdb';
$hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$password = 'quest';
$port = 8812;
$username = 'admin';

$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName;port=$port", $username, $password);
echo '<pre>';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_table");
try {
    $stmt->execute(array());
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Which is returning buggy data, including 1) Wrong values; 2) unreadable characters; 3) correct strings:

```
Array
(
    [personnel_id] => 0 // this is bugged, it should be returning a value of 1...
    [0] => 0
    [ts] => IXO�` // timestamp is bugged
    [1] => IXO�` 
    [date] => ������X // date is bugged
    [2] => ������X 
    [name] => test_string // this string works fine...
    [3] => test_string
    [value] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

Very odd bug -- I do not have any encoding issues with plain `PostgreSQL`, or with my pre-existing `MySQL` tables (which I am trying to switch a few to `QuestDB`).

**Edit**: If I change from `SELECT *` to `SELECT <single_column>` like `SELECT date FROM test_table`, it works fine... But if I add more columns to the query, then the character encoding bugs return.

`QuestDB 6.0.2` and `PHP 8.0.2`

This bug also happens with the pre-installed `telemetry` table, so I don't think it's related to the way I'm creating tables.

Comment: What version of PDO/PHP/QuestDB is it? I created an issue on GH. We will investigate. https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1059

Comment: @VladIlyushchenko `PHP 8.0.2` and `QuestDB 6.0.2` (was unable to find a version for PDO)

Comment: It looks like the issue is closed now: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1059